# PHP: Square brackets in a function's description

Tags: php, manual

I fully understand everything about the following function description aside from the square brackets. What do they mean? And what is the reason for the comma after the opening square-bracket?

Taken from the PHP manual:

**Description**

```
string substr ( string $string , int $start [, int $length ] )
```

I've read through the [FAQs](http://php.net/FAQ.php) but found nothing. Apologies if the question seems basic, it's always been something that has eluded me.

Comment: It mean that that parameter is optional. You can leave it out.

Comment: Thanks. What is the reason for the comma after the first opening square-bracket?

Comment: just to let user know that we need to add comma in case we use this parameter ie substr($mystr,5,3) ... and do not use comma if you are not using last parameter ie it is wrong to use last comma substr($mystr,5,)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/about.prototypes.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square bracket means the parameter is optional. Means you may choose to ignore length then function will take default value for it that is 1.